# Usage of "rather"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

What's the difference between following sentence:

> She kept herself rather *to* herself in her own pantry.

and

> She rather kept herself to herself in her own pantry.

Are there some omitted words in the former?

Comment: Masa.K is a brand new contributor folks. So it would be nice if anyone who felt they absolutely had to downvote the question (but it's not that objectionable, is it?) were to at least explain *why*.

Comment: @Eden0516 thanks for the edit, but for next time: it's omitted with double t

Answer (score 0):

Edit

1

> She kept herself rather to herself in her own pantry.

2

> She rather kept herself to herself in her own pantry.

*keep oneself to oneself* is an idiom and should not be split.

(2) is hence more appropriate.   Alternatively, you could consider

> She rather kept to herself in her own pantry.

Comment: why do you think these examples are incorrect?

Comment: Thx, @David Siegel.  I have edited my answer.

Comment: the former sentence is an excerpt from a well-known ghost story published around 1900. Since the work is still being read today, I don't think the sentence is incomprehensible….

Comment: @Masa.K, I don't think comprehensiveness is the issue. Both are fine from that point of view. But I agree with Seowjooheng Singapore in that it is better to avoid splitting the idiom. That is not a hard, of course, and fast () rule. But since we're in ELL, it seems a useful one to stick to.

Comment: Also, can you give a source for that ghost story? Google turned up nothing on that precise string.

Comment: @tkp, thank you so much. This is a quote from M.R.James' short story "Lost heart". However, there is a correction. The exact quote was "~ the butler, who as a rule kept himself rather to himself in his own pantry." My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The word "rather" could mean one of two things. One is something like "a little" or "somewhat". The other is something like "instead". It's impossible to say which it is (although the first would be my guess) without the surrounding context.

However, regardless of which of those two meanings was intended, changing the position of "rather" has no effect. Both versions of the sentence mean the same, and both are acceptable. (However, see Seeowjooheng's answer concerning splitting an idiom.)